# Split array s.t sub-arrays sum to original

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I'm trying to figure out a clever way to randomly split a numpy integer array into two parts so that the two parts sum to the original array.

**Example:**

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
b, c = rand_split(a)
# Should give something like
# b = [0, 1, 1, 2], c = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

EDIT: All entries should be non-negative.

Comment: There could be many combinations. So, how would you pick unique ones?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, but I'm only looking for one of them, picked at random.

Comment: Hmm well how about : `[a-a//2, a//2]`?

Comment: I think that will always result in the same split, no? I'm looking for a randomised split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with a list comprehension:

```
b = np.array([np.random.randint(0, n+1) for n in a])
c = a - b
```

This should be faster since it's doing all the work in numpy:

```
b = (np.random.uniform(size=a.shape) * (a + 1)).astype(int)
```

Comment: b and c are both numpy arrays right ? i dont understand "I couldn't find a way to do it with only numpy"

Comment: Nice thought with the second one!